# Saving a canvas image to server using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, save

I know the way to do this with PHP but does anyone know a way of doing it only with JS & HTML?

The canvas image should be saved to a server, not locally.

Comment: Send the data of your canvas to PHP in an Ajax call.

Comment: There's no way, unless your server execute JavaScript, you've tagged this with [php], though.

Comment: But, what are you gonna use backend for actually saving the image server-side.... if you only use JS / HTML you have no server access. Unless you consider node.js under your pretense

Answer (score 2):

For JS in the browser security context, is not allowed to write to the user's file system Or to the server file system.

You must have a server side service that will intercept the file and than save it to the system.

**to achieve it using JS only, you need to use node.js as server side**

Comment: What is node.js? Do you have any good links i can read about it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var data=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Send the data to php in an ajax call